# python and scrapy THE encoding issue

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, utf-8, scrapy

I simple can't figure out! :(
I am scrapping data from an utf-8 encoded site, well that is at least what it says:

```
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
```

I am getting a list of regular unicode strings with XPath selector extract() call:

```
item['city']= element.select('//div[@id="bubble_2"]/div/text()').extract()
```

This is the list:

```
[u'Westbahnhofstr.\xa010', u'72070\xa0T\xfcbingen']
```

Now I join the list into one unicode string:

```
item['city']= "".join(element.select('//div[@id="bubble_2"]/div/text()').extract())
```

So far so good:

```
u'Beim Nonnenhaus\xa0672070\xa0T\xfcbingen'
```

The problem appears while I try to output this unicode string either to screen (print) or to a file (write). whatever I try it returns an error (http://pastebin.com/51DkX2R2):

```
exceptions.UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa0' in   position 11: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I have encoded unicode to byte string before output of course:

```
item['city'].encode('utf-8')
```

This is my pipeline.py and how I use to open and write to my cvs:

```
import csv
import items
import urlparse
import codecs

class DepostPipeline(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.modelsCsv = csv.writer(codecs.open('Dees.csv', mode='w',encoding='utf-8'))
        self.modelsCsv.writerow(['city'])

def process_item(self, item, spider):
    if isinstance(item, items.DetailsItem): 
        item['city'] = item['city'].encode('utf-8')

        self.modelsCsv.writerow([item['city']]) 
        return item
```

The most weird thing is that my system (python on windows) handles unicode strings perfectly:

```
C:\Console2>python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Nov 10 2013, 19:24:18) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> s=u'Beim Nonnenhaus\xa0672070\xa0T\xfcbingen'
>>> print s
Beim Nonnenhaus 672070 Tübingen
```

I have been reading about utf-8, unicode, encoding and decoding a lot over the last 10 days but it seems that I still miss something here?!
I appreciate any help or advice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are ignoring the result of the `.encode()` call:

```
item['city'].encode('utf-8')
```

Strings are immutable, and are not encoded in-place. Even better, the *type of the returned object* is different. You'll need to assign the return value back:

```
item['city'] = item['city'].encode('utf-8')
```

However, you should **not** use `codecs.open()` for the CSV file. The `csv` module will always write bytestrings, not Unicode.

By using a `codecs.open()` file object, an implicit **decode** takes place to get back to Unicode, and it is *that* that fails for you; it is why you get a `UnicodeDecodeError` exception, not an encode error:

```
  File "C:\Python27\lib\codecs.py", line 351, in write
    data, consumed = self.encode(object, self.errors)
exceptions.UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 11: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Use a regular `open()` call instead:

```
self.modelsCsv = csv.writer(open('Dees.csv', mode='wb'))
```

Note the `'wb'`; the `csv` module handles line endings itself.

Comment: Sorry, somehow I missed that from my code, it was already on place...I am editing my post. Thanks for respond.

Comment: @mrki: right, that's because you are using `codecs.open()`; I missed that. For a next time, including the traceback in your question would be very helpful! :-)

Comment: I really didn't see that from the error trackback :( you are saving my life now :) I have been using open() call in all my previous crawlers. This time I really thought that I need an utf-8 file to store details as byte strings rather then unicode strings. But why whould I need that now if I simple can choose encoding if I need to open my file for manual edit. What a mess! Though a very much good experience for me! Thanks Martijn!

Answer (score -1):

You can use "ignore" parameter:

```
item['city'].encode('utf-8', 'ignore')
```

https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html#the-unicode-type

Comment: UTF-8 can handle *all* Unicode codepoints; there is nothing *to* ignore here.